# jQuery.ajax(): Can't access two returned json objects (jsonp)

Tags: javascript, json, jquery, jsonp

If this is a duplicate question I will happily be redirected to an answer :).

**Some background:**

I have a small object that handles JSONP requests.

Until recently I was handling the requests using pure JavaScript like this...

```
this.fetchJsonp = function(){

     //the 'request' variable holds the URL and parameters for the request.

     var request = this.request;

     //creates a script element

     var jsonpCall = document.createElement('script');

     //gets jsonp request
     jsonpCall.src = request;

     //adds script to DOM, which goes on to request the JSONP from the service.
     document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jsonpCall);

};
```

After this code is executed, a callback function is called and the JSONP objects are passed to it. Because of the way the service being called is set up, the service sends me two JSONP objects in this format:

```
callbackWrapperFunc({"arrayName":[{item1:"hello",item2:"world"}]}, {anotherImportantItem:"!"});
```

I could pass in these objects to the callback function as thus...

```
this.myCallBackFunction(firstObject, secondObject){

   //manipulate data here 

}
```

**The issue:**

I have since changed my approach and I am now using jQuery to handle the JSONP requests because it allows me to handle errors more easily.

```
//snippet of my jQuery ajax call:

jQuery.ajax({
       url: this.request,
       type: 'get',
       dataType: 'jsonp',

       success: function(firstObject, secondObject) {

                      //manipulate data here

                }

       });
```

I know that the parameters passed into 'success' will not work in the same way as my original code because the jQuery ajax object returns the second and third parameters as a textStatus (detailing whether the call was a success or failure) and the jqXHR object.

The first parameter that gives me access to the data only gives me access to the first JSON object and not the second. I cannot seem to find a way to access the second object (I have also tried to 'cycle' through the objects but to no avail: perhaps I am doing it wrong?).

This is probably really straightforward knowing me! Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How do you send two JSON Objects in your server-side script ?!!?! why don't you send two objects in an array ? like this : [{..}, {..}]

Comment: Whilst what you're doing is *totally* possible, for some reason JSONP has evolved such that it is expected/assumed (through no technical limitation!) that only a single argument will be passed to the callback function. Because of this, I wouldn't be suprised (haven't got time to check the source) if jQuery just plain *doesn't* handle this; you might have to consider @Mohebifar's approach of passing a single array containing both objects, or passing a parent-object of which both your objects are properties.

Comment: Hi guys. This is what I have feared myself. I will have to look into @Mohebifar's suggestion. Thanks for the quick response guys.

Comment: I suggest just continuing doing what you're already doing, jQuery can't really handle jsonp errors properly anyway. From the `$.ajax`documentation for error: *"Note: This handler is not called for cross-domain script and cross-domain JSONP requests."* http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax

Comment: @Kevin B: Hey there. I have been thinking this too. My reasoning behind using the ajax object in jQuery was because, despite that it cant handle errors cross-domain, the 'success' functionality still gave my code a hint if it had received the data or not to start my own error handling process. I'm going to try to come up with a pure JS alternative.

Comment: You could always just use $.getScript. Define your global callback, then get the script.

Comment: no need for jsonp because it's not cross-domain. just use the common ajax functions

Comment: Hi there, JSONP _is_ used for cross-domain queries. Here's some more info http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP... the web service doesn't belong on the same domain, which is why I'm using it :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to come up with a solution. Thank you to @Matt for the inspiration.

**Catch-up...**

This indeed does look like a limitation in jQuery and, as pointed out, accepting one JSON object into the callback function is, seemingly, an expected norm.

If you are in my position, and would like to accept one or more JSON objects into the callback via a web service I have developed a small solution:

## **Solution**

I am no longer using jQuery, I am using the original way I was calling JSON objects from the web service.

In my JSON handler object I have written a custom callback function that takes in multiple JSON objects and processes them into one object for convenience.

```
    this.processJSON = function(){

        //places any number of arguments (json objects) from the service into one JSON object.

        var data = {};

        for(var i = 0; i <= arguments.length; i++){

           data[i] = arguments[i];

        };

        that.callback(data); //sends data to user designated callback

    };
```

This function simply reads how many `arguments` (in this case, JSON objects) are being placed into the function's `arguments` array and processes them all into the one `data` object.

You can then send it to wherever you would like it to go.

Please note that the callback function that calls this function process must be global so that it is recognised in the correct scope. For example, I implemented it by placing this function within my JSON handling object:

```
    window.jsonCallback = function(){

        //this function is executed if the script is successful
        that.call = true;
        that.processJSON(arguments);

    };
```

Example web service call:

`www.myservice.com/service?value="something"&callback=jsonCallback`

`that` refers to the scope of the JSONobject, so it knows where to look for the functions that are being called. The `call` variable is to do with error handling (which I had also found a solution for without jQuery) but is outside the scope of this answer.

I hope this helps anyone looking to handle multiple JSON objects being passed from a web service into their application.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use a PageMethod call in the JavaScript and construct a list of value pairs to send back?

Comment: Hi there :). I believe PageMethods are unique to ASP.NET, which I am not using. However, thank you for the suggestion.